# How do save an object?

Tags: angular

I need to keep the object like this:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "parent": {
        "id":  "70abe1d4-cd03-4987-8bb3-6adf35d82cf9"
    }
}
```

I've tried it this way, but it doesn't work.

```
  initializeForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group(
      {
        name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        parent: {
          id:  new FormControl(this.parent)
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: What is `this.parent`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Angular Reactive Form supports multiple form groups.
[Doc](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupName)

```
this.form = this.fb.group(
            {
                name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
                parent: this.fb.group({
                    id: ['', Validators.required]
                })
            }
        );
```